# Crear Consulta WHERE al modelo con una relacion MorphOne

Tags: laravel, eloquent

como haría  para obtener registros de mi modelo Pettype aplicando un where pero de una columna de una tabla Morph

Ejecuto este comando en el tinker

```
App\Pettype::with('media')->get();
```

Obtengo estos registros pero quisiera que no se este en el listado los registros que tengan valor **NCF** en el **path** que esta en **media**

```
 App\Pettype::with('media')->get();
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4284
     all: [
       App\Pettype {#4316
         id: 10,
         description: "NCF",
         created_at: "2021-01-08 23:05:45",
         updated_at: "2021-01-08 23:05:45",
         deleted_at: null,
         media: App\Media {#4336
           id: 78,
           path: "NCF",
           fileable_type: "App\Pettype",
           fileable_id: 10,
           created_at: "2021-01-08 23:05:45",
           updated_at: "2021-01-08 23:05:45",
         },
       },
       App\Pettype {#4317
         id: 9,
         description: "vacuno",
         created_at: "2021-01-08 23:05:29",
         updated_at: "2021-01-08 23:05:29",
         deleted_at: null,
         media: App\Media {#4335
           id: 77,
           path: "https://conceptodefinicion.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/ganadovacuno.jpg",
           fileable_type: "App\Pettype",
           fileable_id: 9,
           created_at: "2021-01-08 23:05:29",
           updated_at: "2021-01-08 23:05:29",
         },
       },
```

Aqui dejo la config de modelo Pettype a Media

```
public function media()
{
    return $this->morphOne(Media::class,'fileable');
}
```

Aqui dejo la config de Media

```
public function mediable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

y esta en la migracion

```
  Schema::create('media', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('path');
            $table->morphs('fileable');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Quiero que no se registre los registros de App\Pettype  que tengan path NCF y los demas si
[image: esto es lo que deseo obtener]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método `with` acepta un array de tipo `clave => valor` donde la clave sería la relación definida y el valor sería una función por medio de la cual podemos construir un query interno que nos ayude a establecer filtros para los datos que nos retorna dicha consulta, con una estructura similar a la siguiente:

```
with(['relacion' => fn($query) => $query->where........])
```

Entonces debería alcanzar con realizar lo siguiente:

```
App\Pettype::with(['media' => fn($query) => $query->where('path', '<>', 'NCF')])->get();
```

**Referencias**

- [Constraining eager loads](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)
- [Arrow functions en PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.arrow.php)